# computing the output of ternary operation

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I am trying to solve this problem, but can not find the correct way of doing this.

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c = 20; 
int result = a < b ? a < c ? c : a : b; 
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Please suggest how can I compute this problem.

Comment: your code gives you the correct answer in for the given values. but will give the wrong output when a<b and b>c

Comment: You mentioned the solution but not the problem, what problem your trying to solve ? Min between 3 numbers using ternary operation ? text book XY-Problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you write your expression like below, then it will be more clear:

```
int result = (a < b ) ? ((a < c ) ? c : a) : b;
```

> What does the conditional operator?

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

For further documentation on this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Now, let's do the calculation in "paper":

```
a < b
```

is true. So, the condition `a < c` will be evaluated. This condition is also true. Hence, the result would be equal to the value stored to `c`, 20. That's all.

> I have one confusion. I read that ternary operators are RIGHT
>   ASSOCIATIVE. Does it mean that in the problem the part ((a < c ) ? c :
>   a) should be evaluated first? Please explain this.

According to C# specification, [conditional operator](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/14.12.htm):

> The conditional operator is right-associative, meaning that operations
>   are grouped from right to left. For example, an expression of the
>   form a ? b : c ? d : e is evaluated as a ? b : (c ? d : e).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have one confusion. I read that **ternary operators** are **RIGHT ASSOCIATIVE**. Does it mean that in the problem the part `((a < c ) ? c : a)` should be evaluated first? Please explain this.

Comment: You are welcome ! Please take a look here http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/14.12.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a biggest number.

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c = 20; 
int result = a > b ? a > c ? a : c > b ? c : b : b > c ? b : c;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It is equivalent to the following if-else condition. I have identified each part with `((...))`

```
if (a > b)                  //((a > b ?)) a > c ? a : c > b ? c : b : b > c ? b : c
{
    if (a > c)              //a > b ? ((a > c ?)) a : c > b ? c : b : b > c ? b : c
    {
        result = a;         //a > b ? a > c ? ((a)) : c > b ? c : b : b > c ? b : c
    }
    else if (c > b)         //a > b ? a > c ? a ((: c > b ?)) c : b : b > c ? b : c
    {
        result = c;         //a > b ? a > c ? a : c > b ? ((c)) : b : b > c ? b : c
    }
    else
    {
        result = b;         //a > b ? a > c ? a : c > b ? c ((: b)) : b > c ? b : c
    }
}
else if (b > c)             //a > b ? a > c ? a : c > b ? c : b ((: b > c ?)) b : c
{
   result = b;              //a > b ? a > c ? a : c > b ? c : b : b > c ? ((b)) : c
}
else
{
   result = c;              //a > b ? a > c ? a : c > b ? c : b : b > c ? b ((: c))
}
```

If you want **smallest** number just negate `>`.

```
int result = a < b ? a < c ? a : c < b ? c : b : b < c ? b : c;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given:

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c = 20; 
int result = a < b ? a < c ? c : a : b; 
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

transaltes to:

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c = 20; 
int result;
if (a < b)
{ 
    if (a < c)
    {
        result = c;
    }
    else
    {
        result = a;
    }
}
else
{
    result = b;
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Therefore, the problem is that if a is less than b, then without checking b against c, you are setting result to b.

If you insist on using ternary operators, the condition should be:

```
int result = a < b ? (a < c ? a : (b < c ? b : c)) : (b < c ? b : c);
```

The translation is simple. Let me know if you want it elaborated.